# How to get oozie jobId in oozie workflow?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, workflow, oozie

I have a oozie workflow that will invoke a shell file, Shell file will further invoke a driver class of mapreduce job. Now i want to map my oozie jobId to Mapreduce jobId for later process. Is there any way to get oozie jobId in workflow file so that i can pass the same as argument to my driver class for mapping.

Following is my sample workflow.xml file

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="test">
<start to="start-test" />
<action name='start-test'>
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <exec>${jobScript}</exec>
        <argument>${fileLocation}</argument>
        <argument>${nameNode}</argument>
        <argument>${jobId}</argument> <!-- this is how i wanted to pass oozie jobId --> 
        <file>${jobScriptWithPath}#${jobScript}</file>
    </shell>
    <ok to="end" />
    <error to="kill" />
</action>
<kill name="kill">
    <message>test job failed
        failed:[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end" />
```

Following is my shell script.

```
hadoop jar testProject.jar testProject.MrDriver $1 $2 $3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `${wf:id()}`:

> String wf:id()
>
> It returns the workflow job ID for the current workflow job.

[More info here.](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html)

Answer (score 2):

Oozie drops an XML file in the CWD of the YARN container running the shell (the "launcher" container), and also sets an env variable pointing to that XML *(cannot remember the name though)*.

That XML contains a lot of stuff like name of Workflow, name of Action, ID of both, run attempt number, etc.
So you can `sed` back that information in the shell script itself.

Of course passing explicitly the ID (as suggested by Alexei) would be cleaner, but sometimes "clean" is not the best way. Especially if you are concerned about whether it's the first run or not...

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve workflow info (or the xml file) from a program run by that oozie workflow?

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I tried to go through all env variables available to my program but can't find anything helpful. But I managed to do it by calling oozie cli and filter the response.